# Convert [][]interface to [][]string

Tags: json, go, slice

Is there any easy way to convert `[][] interface{}` to `[][]string` ?
What I want is to to write this `[][] interface{}` to a `csv` but `writer` in `go`  accepts only `[][]string`.
Additional info : my `[][] interface{}` contains 4 columns 2 of them are string and 2 are `json.Number`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Adrian , isn't that backwards? OP wants to go __from__ an `interface{}`, not __to__ an `interface{}`

Comment: It doesn't matter, the issue is still the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest way is probably to make new slices and write some loops:

```
var orig [][]interface{}
var strs = make([][]string, len(orig))
for i := range orig {
   strs[i] = make([]string, len(orig[i]))
   for j := range orig[i]{
     strs[i][j] = fmt.Sprint(orig[i][j])
   }
}
```

Comment: I think this is the only way to go :)

Comment: In the first line, `var orig [][]interface` should read `var orig [][]interface{}`.

Comment: correct, thanks @sebastian